# Why did the blood sacrifice in Genesis take place as acceptable to God?

Tags: sacrifice

I have asked pastors where is it commanded by God to have a blood sacrifice as an offering in Genesis since that is the beginning.  It doesn't seem to be explained until Leviticus.  Can someone please tell me if God commanded this to be done in Genesis? Where in Genesis was it commanded that sacrifice was necessary.  From what I am reading it appears to be open as an interpretation.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail, quoting some relevant passages, what exactly you're asking about?

Comment: I do not see in Genesis where a blood sacrifice was commanded by God before Cain and Able offered their respective sacrifices; thus, leading me to believe that it is all interpretative to the individual.  No passages can I find, that's why I am asking.  The book of Moses I do not find in the bible.  As a new Christian I do not recognize what the Pearl of Great Price in Book of Moses Reshwity commented on.  Can you explain?

Comment: The "Book of Moses" in Pearl of Great Price is a Mormon (LDS) thing only. No other Christians follow it or believe it. If you are not a Mormon, then you're looking in the wrong place for answers.

Comment: Regarding the question, is there a reason to believe that it was not commanded, simply because it is not recorded in Genesis? After all, they start sacrificing and God looks favorably on Able's but not Cain's, so it seems reasonable to me to assume that God did command it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who instituted the practice of sacrifice?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14879/who-instituted-the-practice-of-sacrifice)

Comment: Related: [Did Adam and Eve ever practice animal sacrifice?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/14861/3961)

Answer (score 2):

In the Pearl of Great Price in the book of Moses it says:(Moses 5:5-7)

> 5 And he gave unto them commandments, that they should worship the
>   Lord their God, and should offer the firstlings of their flocks, for
>   an offering unto the Lord. And Adam was obedient unto the commandments
>   of the Lord.
>
> 6 And after many days an angel of the Lord appeared unto Adam,
>   saying: Why dost thou offer sacrifices unto the Lord? And Adam said
>   unto him: I know not, save the Lord commanded me.
>
> 7 And then the angel spake, saying: This thing is a similitude of the
>   sacrifice of the Only Begotten of the Father, which is full of grace
>   and truth.

When Adam left the Garden of Eden he was commanded by God to give a sacrifice. We see this is continued on by his sons with the whole Cain and Abel situation. It was meant as a similitude of Christs sacrifice. So when Christ died on the cross that law was fulfilled and it was no longer needed for man to sacrifice living animals though Christ has asked other sacrifices of man.

I don't think there is anything written in Genesis specifically if you look at it chronologically but if you look at the story of Abraham and his son Isaac Genesis talks about sacrifice there. But it doesn't explain anything or imply whether sacrifice had been happening before. It is an interesting story as Abraham was almost sacrificed by his own father and that was the reason he left his homeland, so for him to do the same to his only son was very significant.

It was probably written in other scriptures that have not survived to this time era, which is unfortunate as that would have been interesting.

Comment: I don't think the asker is looking for LDS answers. [According to his comment:](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/38523/why-did-the-blood-sacrifice-in-genesis-take-place-as-acceptable-to-god#comment105640_38523) `The book of Moses I do not find in the bible. As a new Christian I do not recognize what the Pearl of Great Price in Book of Moses Reshwity commented on.`

Answer (score 0):

From the beginning, the requirement of a sacrifice as a substitute for their sins was communicated to them verbally. It is not found directly in Genesis, but strongly inferred in Genesis 4 when Abel's animal sacrifice was accepted over Caine's offering of fruits. The act of offering an animal sacrifice was an acknowledgement of their need for a savior, for by their own merits they can never atone for sin.

> And in the process of time it came to pass that Cain brought an
>   offering of the fruit of the ground to the Lord. Abel also brought of
>   the firstborn of his flock and of their fat. And the Lord respected
>   Abel and his offering, but He did not respect Cain and his offering.
>   (Genesis 4:3-5)

The next verse implies that Cain knew what was the right way but chose not to do it.

> So the Lord said to Cain, Why are you angry? And why has your countenance fallen? If you do well, will you not be accepted?" (Genesis 4:6-7)

Paul also elaborate further on this event:

> By faith Abel offered to God a more excellent sacrifice than Cain,
>   through which he obtained witness that he was righteous, God
>   testifying of his gifts; and through it he being dead still speaks. (Hebrews 11:4)

In addition to Genesis 4, we has have evidence of the very first animal sacrifice. An animal was slain to make clothes for Adam and Eve in place of their covering of leaves.

> "Also for Adam and his wife the Lord God made tunics of skin, and
>   clothed them." (Genesis 3:21)

We are to take off our own filthy robes and put on the robe of Christ (Zech 3:4)

Comment: Cain's sacrifice was not rejected because it was not an animal, it was rejected because it was the inferior part of his yield rather than the best. This is repeated several times in the Pentateuch, where God demands that sacrificial animals be without blemish. Any offering to God must have no imperfections, and that is the reason only the sacrifice of the sinless man Jesus is our acceptable substitute sacrifice.

Comment: You and I share a difference of interruption. Not sure why I deserve a down vote though. See http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16223/why-did-god-accept-abels-offering-and-not-cains/

Comment: If you read the first paragraph of the accepted answer you will see that it agrees with my opinion. The down vote was because there is no backing for your assertion of the skins being an animal sacrifice. The Bible gives us no indication that animals were killed; God who created the whole animal was surely capable of creating skins alone. Also God had already given man dominion over the animals, and it seems contrary to the nature of God to kill innocent animals for such a trivial purpose as clothing man.

Comment: I know the accepted answer shared your opinion, but other answers shared other interruptions. The purpose was not to clothe man but an act that points forward to the lamb of God which takes away sins.

Comment: @Bye That argument might mean something more if there was a single example of vegetables being an acceptable sacrifice.

Comment: @fredsbend Exo 29:23  one loaf of bread, one cake made with oil, and one wafer from the basket of the unleavened bread that is before the LORD; 
Exo 29:24  and you shall put all these in the hands of Aaron and in the hands of his sons, and you shall wave them as a wave offering before the LORD. 
Exo 29:25  You shall receive them back from their hands and burn them on the altar as a burnt offering, as a sweet aroma before the LORD. It is an offering made by fire to the LORD.

Comment: @Bye A thanks offering is not the same as a sacrificial offering. It would be as if our tithing represents the sacrifice of Jesus. Taken a bit deeper, the wave offering points forward to the resurrection of Jesus on Sunday, but there must be a sacrifice in the first place...

Comment: @Bye What Beestocks said. That is a description of an offering, not a sacrifice.

Comment: @fredsbend/Beestocks We have gone afar from my original objection which has to do with Cain's offering as opposed to Abel's which were offerings and not sacrifices. in fact we do not know that Abel's offering was a sacrifice since Scriptures do not say that his offering was slain. I did not intend to begin an argument about what constitutes a sacrifice only that Cain and Abel made a difference in the quality of their **offerings**. We have no way of knowing whether or not sacrifices were made prior to Moses time, since Scriptures do not say.

Comment: @Bye fair point, it was nice discussing with you nevertheless. The first explicit sacrifice was by Noah after the flood. Think of the precious animals Noah kept in the ark for months on end, only to be sacrificed as soon as they land.

Comment: @Bye Noah sacrificed in [Genesis 8:20](http://biblehub.com/genesis/8-20.htm). Abraham sacrificed in [Genesis 22:13](http://biblehub.com/genesis/22-13.htm). The phrase "burnt offering" is always in context of fat portions and sacrifice. Abel brought a fat portion (presumably to be burned because that is what you do with the fat protions). It's not good hermeneutics to claim Abel was doing something else. It's also outside of the widely common belief that Abel's offering was indeed a sacrifice.

Comment: @fredsbend I admit that Noah did sacrifice, something I should have remembered. However, Genesis 4:4  Abel also brought of **the firstborn of his flock and of their fat.** And the LORD respected Abel and his offering, That does not say that he either killed the sheep or burned the fat. Also even if most theologians did believe it was a sacrifice does not make it so. I personally only affirm what the Bible tells me and any commentary is just that; commentary or someone's understanding. This will be my last comment since this has deviated too far from the question itself.

Comment: @Bye Then you need to stop saying that Cain's offering was refused because it was part of an inferior portion of his yield.

Answer (score 0):

In Genesis God told Adam that:

> Genesis 2:17 NKJV  but of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil you shall not eat, for in the day that you eat of it you shall surely die."

In the original Hebrew the word used here is:

תָּמֽוּת׃  tā·mūṯ.

you will die

And if we break that down even farther, according to Brown Driver and Briggs:

מוּת  mûth

BDB Definition:

1) to die, kill, have one executed

1a) (Qal)

1a1) to die

1a2) to die (as penalty), be put to death

1a3) to die, perish (of a nation)

1a4) to die prematurely (by neglect of wise moral conduct)

1b) (Polel) to kill, put to death, dispatch

1c) (Hiphil) to kill, put to death

1d) (Hophal)

1d1) to be killed, be put to death

1d1a) to die prematurely

Part of Speech: verb

A Related Word by BDB/Strong’s Number: a primitive root

To die is bring life to an end, and God forbad man to eat Blood because:

> Genesis 9:2 through 6 NKJV  And the fear of you and the dread of you shall be on every beast of the earth, on every bird of the air, on all that move on the earth, and on all the fish of the sea. They are given into your hand. 3  Every moving thing that lives shall be food for you. I have given you all things, even as the green herbs. 4  **But you shall not eat flesh with its life, that is, its blood.** 5  ***Surely for your lifeblood I will demand a reckoning; from the hand of every beast I will require it,*** and from the hand of man. From the hand of every man's brother I will require the life of man. 6 "Whoever sheds man's blood, By man his blood shall be shed; For in the image of God He made man.

In Leviticus God allowed the substitution of the life of animals as a substitute for the life of man in the letting of the animals blood as stated in ***Surely for your lifeblood I will demand a reckoning; from the hand of every beast I will require it,***

In the same manner as he allowed the blood (life) of Jesus to atone for our sins.

The sacrificial system instituted by God in the Old Testament is a prevue to the sacrifice of Jesus.

Just as the blood of the animals is only representative of forgiveness, it was of no value without repentance, So is the blood of Christ only representative of our forgiveness without repentance.

From the very beginning God declared that sin can only be washed in blood.

Either our sins will be washed in the blood of Christ or it will be washed in our own blood:

> Revelation 20:14 and 15 NKJV  Then Death and Hades were cast into the lake of fire. This is the second death. 15  And anyone not found written in the Book of Life was cast into the lake of fire.